# Git asking for password.

Tags: git, github, ssh, passwords

I'm trying to set up my computer to be using my github account, here's what I've got:

In my locally where the project is kept:

```
 $ git remote -v 
 origin ssh://git@github.com/djleprechaunz/OscProject.git (fetch)
 origin ssh://git@github.com/djleprechaunz/OscProject.git (push)
```

and

```
ssh-add -l
2048 [key1] dave@mycomputername (RSA)
2048 [key2] myemail@gmail.com (RSA)
```

(Sorry, not sure about the security of posting the whole key up).

When I try

```
git fetch
```

it pops up with a dialog 'An application wants access to the private key 'myemail@gmail.com', but it is locked'

What should I be doing here? I tried putting in my github password, but that doesn't work.

Comment: It sounds like that private key is encrypted with its own password.

Comment: You can also give the same passphrase which you have gave while creating the ssh (private-public key pair) if you have remembered. :)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

you need to put the passphrase you entered while creating the ssh key when it prompts for the password

Comment: I can't for the life of me remember what it was :(

Comment: ha ha just remove the previous ssh and create a new ssh with known paraphase

Comment: You can also give the same passphrase which you have gave while creating the ssh (private-public key pair) if you have remembered. :)

Comment: you are a savior. Thanks